# Save array from drop-down menu in Wordpress

Tags: arrays, wordpress

I have successfully pulled a custom post type through into a drop-down that is in a custom meta box. However, when displaying it on the front end I would like to also provide a link to the actual post, not just the name of the post. So I am guessing I need to save this as an array? Is this possible through a drop-down? Confused on how I should approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Add Meta Box To Select Overseeing Pastor
add_action('admin_init', 'ministry_select_add_meta');
function ministry_select_add_meta(){
    add_meta_box('ministry_select_post', __('Overseeing Pastor'), 'ministry_select_meta', 'ministry', 'side');
}

function ministry_select_meta( $post ) {
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $selected = isset( $values['pastor_select'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['pastor_select'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
        <select name="pastor_select">
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'employee',
                'position' => 'pastor'
            );
            $pastorList = new WP_Query($args); while ($pastorList->have_posts()) : $pastorList->the_post();
                $is_selected = (get_the_title() == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option value="'.get_the_title().'" '.$is_selected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </select>
    <?php   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'ministry_select_save' );
function ministry_select_save( $post_id )
{
    // Stop If Autosaving
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // Stop If Nonce Can't Be Verified
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // Stop If Unauthorized User
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Make Sure Data Is Set Then Save      
    if( isset( $_POST['pastor_select'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'pastor_select', esc_attr( $_POST['pastor_select'] ) );
}
```

Comment: why would you want to save the link? and how does your dropdown works?

Comment: I want to be able to specify the link on the front end so it would take you to the Pastor's profile.

Comment: What do you want is go to the Post URL when the Post Title is selected in the Drop Down?

Comment: I would like to select a post type (Pastor) in another post type (Ministry). Once that has been chosen, I would like to populate it on the front end with the name of the Pastor as well as a link that follows to that post (Pastor's Profile). I have the first part working fine, I just need to be able to pull in the link of that post as well so I can grab it and display it on the front end.

Comment: In the reply below I mention the function that gives you the Post URL

Comment: Thanks, but I knew that I could do that. I needed a way to grab the title and the permalink as well. I posted my solution below.

Comment: Yes that's correct, is the same I suggested in the last part of my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a different solution. Instead of trying to save an array, I just saved the post ID which would allow me access to the title of the post as well as the permalink.

This is my modified code

```
<select name="pastor_select">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'employee',
        'position' => 'pastor'
    );
    $pastorList = new WP_Query($args); while ($pastorList->have_posts()) : $pastorList->the_post();
        $employeeID = get_the_ID(); // THIS FIXED THE PROBLEM
        $is_selected = ($employeeID == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo '<option value="'.$employeeID.'" '.$is_selected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</select>
```

And this is how I am calling it on the front end

```
<?php 
$id = $post_meta_data['pastor_select'][0];
echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($id).'">';
echo get_the_title($id);
echo '</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the link of a Post you can use the [get_permalink function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

```
<?php $permalink = get_permalink( ); ?>
```

or like this if you are outside the Loop

```
<?php $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>
```

You can use that to print it in any place on your HTML code.

If what you want is go to the Post URL when the Post Title is selected in the Drop Down you can use JavaScript code to do that, doing something like:

```
<select name="pastor_select" onchange='location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
            <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'employee',
                'position' => 'pastor'
            );
            $pastorList = new WP_Query($args); while ($pastorList->have_posts()) : $pastorList->the_post();
                $is_selected = (get_the_title() == $selected) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
                echo '<option value="'.get_permalink( ).'" '.$is_selected.'>'.get_the_title().'</option>';
            endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </select>
```

If what you want is save some POST information, is recommended save the ID of the POST, so later you can retrieve any data for that POST, what if you want to store permalink and title you can combine the functions get_permalink( ); and get_the_title(); in the select "value" attribute.